# Move the custom pagination and show slide correctly

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

```
<div id="started-carousel">
      <div id="started-panel-01">1</div>
      <div id="started-panel-02">2</div>
      <div id="started-panel-03">3</div>
      <div id="started-panel-04">4</div>
</div>
<div id="started-carousel-nav" class="flex-container">
      <div class="flex-item">1</div>
      <div class="flex-item">2</div>
      <div class="flex-item">3</div>
      <div class="flex-item">4</div>
</div>

$("#started-carousel").owlCarousel({
        dots: false,
        items: 1,
        itemsDesktop: [1199, 1],
        itemsDesktopSmall: [979, 1],
        itemsTablet: [768, 1],
        itemsMobile: [479, 1],
        singleItem: !0,
        slideSpeed: 700,
        rewindNav: !1,
        touchDrag: !1,
        mouseDrag: !1,
        afterAction: t
    });
    var c = $("#started-carousel").data("owlCarousel");
    $("#started-carousel .next").click(function() {
        c.next()
    });
    var s = $("#started-carousel-nav > .flex-item").click(function() {
        var t = s.index(this);
        //c.goTo(t)
       $("#started-carousel").owlCarousel();
       $("#started-carousel").trigger("to.owl.carousel", [0, 500, true]);
    });
```

outside carousel div, the carousel-nav is in its own div.

`c.goTo()` is not a function as console mentioned. checked google and it didn't exist in doc. Found answer on to.owl.carousel and tested. The carousel-nav behaved inaccurately. For example, click on 1, it will not go to slide 1. If click on 2, it will go back to 1. Not sure why it behaved incorrectly. Appreciate help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you do not have to create your navigation. Owl-Carousel has a navigation by default.
You should check here if you are using version 2 : [Docs & Demos](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/basic.html).

If you are using the first version, you should use

```
navigation: true
```

instead of

```
nav: true
```

The library will add the navigation in the DOM itself.